# How to select cells in a row with EXCEL VBA until a cell with a certain value?

Tags: vba, excel

I jus want to select consequent cells in a single row, until a certain cell, with the value "Total" in it. How do I do this in VBA? I'm making a VBA procedure which relies on the length of the row, which must be dynamic (the length can change).

Comment: Instead of looping, use [.FIND](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) Much faster ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Sub test()
    Dim myRow As Long
    Dim rngEnd As Range
    Dim rngToFormat As Range

    myRow = 4
    Set rngEnd = Rows(myRow).Find("total")
    If Not rngEnd Is Nothing Then
        Set rngToFormat = Range(Cells(myRow, 1), rngEnd)
        Debug.Print rngToFormat.Address
    Else
        Debug.Print "No total on row " & myRow
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 on using .Find :)

Comment: OK, thank you for the help, but now I have an Error message when I try to run the code: Set rngToFormat = Range(Cells(myRow, 1), rngEnd) is highlighted, and it's error 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed.

Comment: probably it did not find "total", and therefore `rngEnd` is `Nothing`. You should include a test for that. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a sub:

```
For i = 1 To 9999
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Value = "Total" Then Exit For
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then Exit For
Next
If ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Value = "Total" Then Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + i - 1)).Select
```

The macro select from Activecell to the value of "Total".
If you want from the column 5 (sample):

```
For i = 1 To 9999
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Value = "Total" Then Exit For
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then Exit For
Next
If ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Value = "Total" Then Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 5), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + i - 1)).Select
```

Comment: Cool! I like the code. But it has gotten more complicated. The thing is I want to copy a certain formula dynamically in a row, consequently. The length should be until the cell with the Total value. HOWEVER: I'm copying the formula under a table, so basically there is no cell with a Total value in it, just above a few rows.

Comment: I'm thinking about selecting a range from a fixed N cell until N+M where M = Cell "Total" - N. But of course there is no Total in this row only above it. So I need to count how many cells are there, put the number in a variable M, then add this M to the starting cell. And then I've got the Selection.Range.End cell. Does this make sense?

Comment: So how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FindTotal()
    Dim rng As Variant
    rng = Rows(20) ' Then number of the row where "Total" is. Keep in mind that this will add all columns to rng and which will use a lot of memory. If you can limit the number of columns to be added e.g. rng = Range("A20:Z20") as long as Total will always be within the range
    i = 1
    While rng(1, i) <> "Total"
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```